# One model for many views in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Have a nice day! I just started to learn django framework and faced such problem. I'm making a small site where only one model is required, but this model is used to create pages through a slug, for example:
`domain.com/city/services`
`domain.com/city/services/service-detail`
`domain.com/city/services/service-detail-2`

variables on the page change depending on the value of the slug "city". In all django tutorials, the class in the model is strongly associated with the target template.

```
# appname/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Город на англ")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Основной телефон")
    gorod = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Город")
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Область")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.gorod

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

In the view, too, binding to the model and a specific template

```
# appname/views.py

from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import City


class CityDetailView(DetailView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

And this is my URLS.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import CityDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>', CityDetailView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

How can I write a model so that I can use values in all templates dependent on the slug "city"?

In laravel, I didn't use the database at all. To use slugs, I installed a localization module, where instead of languages I put the city and dependent variables.
In django, I did not find such a solution and decided to go through the models

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can create other views with other templates using the same model. You just need to separate views with distinct URL paths.

Comment: I can, of course, but the model points to a specific template, so I can put relative links in templates

Comment: Can you give and example of the other template you would like to use that model with?